# Are functions labelled "experimental" to be avoided while writing code?

Tags: functions

A number of functions are currently labelled "experimental" on the official [Wolfram Language Documentation Centre](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/). (An example is [AskFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AskFunction.html), which appears to be especially suited to my specific purpose.) Is Wolfram Research trying to caution users against using these functions in their code?

What is the real purpose of the "experimental" label? Are these functions likely to be removed in future versions?

Comment: It mostly just means it's in beta and might change a little: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63Iz3XOYXoA On the other hand experimental functions pretty much change as much as technically finalized ones.